# How to read data from Websphere MQ using jmeter, is there any plugin or utility available?

Tags: jmeter

We are trying to use JMeter for SOA testing to reduce some cost.  Where we are unable to find a utility to option to read data from MQ using JMeter as like we have option in Parasoft SOA test.

Is there a way we can do that in JMeter?

Comment: does this help? https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMSSampler/

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install [WebSphere MQ Client Components](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/clients/) as per your server version
2. Make sure you have all the necessary .jar files in [JMeter CLASSPATH](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (use *search_path* property or copy the .jars to JMeter "lib" folder). JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up
3. Follow instructions from [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) to read the data from the MQ